# Hide few wordpress dashboard option from client

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have just developed a wordpress site for a client. The client wants full access but I dont want to give him access to all the work which I have done (plugins, techniques, themes options etc). How can I give a customized dashboard access to the client with hidden plugins and theme menu items.

Thanks

Comment: I got the solution for same by following the given [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28782/possible-to-hide-custom-post-type-ui-menu-from-specific-user-role)

Answer (score 0):

If you want GUI based approach and not want to handle it via functions, using the [Members](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/) plugin could help

Answer (score 0):

I think you would prefer to go with a plugin rather than pieces of code. You can achieve the same by using a plugin called **[Adminimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/)**

Admins can activate/deactivate every part of the menu and even parts of the sub-menu. Meta fields can be administered separately for posts and pages. Certain parts of the write menu can be deactivated separately for admins or non-admins. The header of the backend is minimized and optimized to give you more space and the structure of the menu gets changed to make it more logical – this can all be done per user so each role and their resulting users can have his own settings.

I hope the above information worked for you.